# Need help to open a subchart from a main chart?

Tags: java, mouseevent, jfreechart

I have the following chart:

[image: chart]

Now my problem is I want to open a new chart containing the information for Linux OS when a user clicks on Linux portion of chart, shown in red. I have tried this:

```
//check if Linux OS is clicked on chart...
if("Linux".equals(chartMouseEvent.getEntity().getToolTipText()))
{
    //open new chart having the information for Linux
}
```

But I think there may be some better alternate to do the same job.
So please help if you know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ChartEntity`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/entity/ChartEntity.html) is a good choice, but `getToolTipText()` is not the only resource available. The `getURLText()` method is also handy, using the information provided by the [`StandardPieURLGenerator`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/urls/StandardPieURLGenerator.html). Alternatively, a custom implementation of [`PieURLGenerator`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/urls/PieURLGenerator.html) can access the data set directly:

```
plot.setURLGenerator(new PieURLGenerator() {
    public String generateURL(PieDataset dataset, Comparable key, int pieIndex) {
        // access the dataset as required
    }
});
```