# JfreeChart tooltips with HTML code inside

Tags: html, jfreechart, tooltip

It is possible to use HTML in JFreeChart tooltips?

I extend StandardCategoryToolTipGenerator and override method generateToolTip

```
public String generateToolTip(Dataset dataset, int row,
        int column, int row) {

    return "<h1>ToolTips on line 1<\\h1> <br /> Second line tooltip"

}
```

But it is displaying whole string instead.
Does anyone know how to display html text in jfrechart tooltips?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`CategoryURLGenerator`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/urls/CategoryURLGenerator.html), illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291045/need-help-to-open-a-subchart-from-a-main-chart/6295405#6295405) for the homologous [`PieURLGenerator`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/urls/PieURLGenerator.html).

Addendum: As the tool tips are not Swing components, HTML is not supported. You can retrieve the result from your chosen [URL generator](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/urls/package-summary.html) in a `ChartMouseListener` to achieve any desired result.

Comment: Using URL generator I will generate URL link for some part of the chart. What I want ,it is simply to display a tooltip having HTML inside.(for example multilene tooltip)

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the essential aspect of your question; I've elaborated above.