# understanding piechart in jfreechart

Tags: java, jfreechart, pie-chart

```
public static JFreeChart createPieChart(java.lang.String title,
                        PieDataset dataset,
                        boolean legend,
                        boolean tooltips,
                        boolean urls)
```

I want to know about using the last parameter urls;

what does it means?

any example of it?

**Configure chart to generate URLs?** what does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By googling i found this code of the `ChartFactory` http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/gjdoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory-source.html

Looking in the test of using urls there a instance of a new `StandardPieURLGenerator`

The jsfreechart help tells:

```
Interface for a URL generator for plots that use data from a PieDataset. Classes that implement this interface:
 - are responsible for correctly escaping any text that is derived from the dataset, as this may be user-specified and could pose a security risk;
 - should be either (a) immutable, or (b) cloneable via the PublicCloneable interface (defined in the JCommon class library). This provides a mechanism for the referring plot to clone the generator if necessary.
```

http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/urls/PieURLGenerator.html

I hope this can help.

Comment: can you please provide link of example that implements it .

Comment: @HemantMetalia: There's an example using `StandardPieURLGenerator` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6295405/230513).