# JFree chart Drill-Down bar chart

Tags: java, mouseevent, jfreechart, bar-chart

I am new to `JFreeChart` and all I want is to open a sub-chart from my main-chart.

**My main chart is like this :**

[image]

Now, I want to open a new chart ***on-click*** of each bar.

I've done some ***research*** for this and all I've got is...

1. [Need help to open a subchart from a main chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6291045/2764279)
2. [Bar Chart Example](http://web37249.server37.mivitec.net/jfreechart-sample/bar_chart.jsp)

but still doesn't understand how to achieve this. Please help me to get through this (*any other source to get more knowledge about JFreeChart Drill-down appreciated*)...

Comment: More examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20%5bjfreechart%5d%20ChartEntity).

Comment: @trashgod I want to put it on my web-app (JSP) as on 2nd example stated above, but doesn't know how...:(:(:(

Comment: Please update your question to clarify this requirement. I use [tag:java-web-start] to deploy interactive applications. I'm not familiar with the `WebHitDataSet` used in the second example.